# Slick Slider isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I have been trying to get slick slider (Centre mode)to work on my website. I have added 'Slick' folder into my websites folder. I'm not sure if it is because i am linking it wrong or if the JavaScript isn't working? Any help would be appreciated a lot!

This is my HTML:
https://pastebin.com/5chBPzzi

This is CSS:

```
 .navbar{
    margin-bottom:0;
    border-radius:0;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a{
    color: #ff6501;
}

.jumbotron{
    background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
    background-size:cover;
}

.slick-slide {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.slick-slide.slick-center {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This is the script:

```
    $('.center').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 3
});
```

Thanks, Jacob

Comment: If you're linking it wrong, the javascript console will tell you.  It'll indicate a 404 error meaning it couldn't find the resource.  What does your javascript console display as far as errors go?

Comment: @JosephMarikle This is it, nothing else. http://imgur.com/a/HTrbf

I have no idea why is isn't working then D:

Comment: That's not your javascript console.  That's jslint.  jslint is a *pre*processor that checks your code before runtime.  What browser are you using to test this site with?  Although the warning about `$` is concerning.  You could be executing that script before you load jQuery or jQuery is not loading correctly which would break slick.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Ahh, I am using Chrome. i went to 'inspect' then clicked console and no errors showed up at all.  So maybe it has something to do with my jquery?

Comment: That's good.  You've found the javascript console.  Now make sure that's open and refresh the page.  Also, make sure that the dropdown to the left of the "Filter" text box says "top".  If there are any syntax errors, they should show up there.

Comment: @JosephMarikle The only error I am getting is "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" Which is just my image I have not loading. Nothing about Javascript or anything.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I refreshed the page and from that error message said above turned into this. http://imgur.com/a/uWK8F so maybe my jQuery isn't working properly? I don't really know much about jquery.

Comment: I doubt that error is any indication jQuery isn't working.  Possibly a logic or styling error.  Let me see if I can reproduce the code on jsfiddle.

Comment: Your code seems to be working.  http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/LpLmmm4n/.  What are the contents of `js/script.js`?

Comment: Could it be as simple as you needing to use `$('.slider')` instead of `$('.center')`?

Comment: @JosephMarikle This whole time it was a matter of needing to put .slider instead of .center. Wow, i feel foolish, haha. Thank you so much !

Comment: No worries.  Glad it's fixed even if it was just a typo, and everyone makes typos now and then.